# Learning to chant Torah with trope

Tags: torah-reading, trop-cantillation, memory

It takes me at least 3-4 hours (cumulative) to learn 5-10 psukim (sentences) in trope. This is just one Aliyah! And unlike many of you, I know the notes, the grammar, and understand most of the words. Yet it takes so long. I remember as a child that my Orthodox Grandfather z"l prepared and was able to learn & chant (lein) an ENTIRE Parasha in practically no time. What am I missing?

Comment: Someone who does enough Torah readings eventually can intuit what the te'amim will be based on the word count between the beginning of the verse and the atnah/etnahta and between the atnah to the sof pasuk

Comment: Check out _Moonwalking with Einstein_

Comment: It's normal for it to take hours and hours. But a bit sticks in your memory for the next year, so that year is easier, and so on.

Comment: I have a horrible memory, but by doing שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום for a few years now, it's become far better. It gets to your brain in an unconscious way as well. Take your time...

Comment: You can get an intuitive sense for what te'amim will be there just by listening to a (good) baal koreh and paying attention. After that all you need to memorize are the more "complicated" pieces.

Comment: I can fudge it the way you're suggesting very easily but I want to get every note right and you cannot sense that. There are too many variations.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback and גמר חתימה טובה לכולם!

Comment: @Esther this in simply not true, unless you lein in a place where no one cares.

Comment: @paquda a few pesukim shouldn't take more than a few minutes. A whole parsha can take many hours. It also depends if you are trying to memorize for the immediate use, that doesn't take to long for a few pesukin, vs if you need for a day later or so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Understanding the trop will help immensely (i.e. which is a "mesharet" - helper vs which is a "Mafsik")
2. Many parshiyos have very similar words with slightly different trop, keeping track of those and trying to remember the different tunes will help.
3. Trying to understand the pasuk being leined while leining it can help (this can be pretty hard for beginners)
4. Using a good token Korim can make a huge difference (for one, the צורת הדף will be very similar to the one in the actual torah , for many torah's)

For all the above I would greatly suggest the Tikkun Kotrim called "Simanim" by Rabbi Riachi. It has a terrific intro explaining some basics of dikduk and trop, and he came up with a good way to point to many items to remember withing the text of the pesukim.

You can purchase it [here](https://judaicaplaza.com/products/17802696?_pos=26&_sid=c24661d74&_ss=r) (if you are sefardi, make sure to get the nusach עדות המזרח version)

Comment: I would like to thank everyone. I must say that since asking this question, I discovered that when I translate the psukim, I have a dramatically easier time remembering the trope!  !חג שמח לכולם